# Auto Update ListView once a new Record Inserted to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, webforms

I've (2) applications one is Website and the Second is Application to manage the requests which is coming from the Website.

When I submit RegisterationForm and record get inserted in SQL Srv DB, I want the
ListView of registered clients notified that there is a new update , and Perform an Update on ListView without refreshing the Page Always.

So it will be easy for the Admin to monitor the new Registered Clients on listview. WHAT I MEAN IS THE LISTVIEW MUST BE REALTIME.

I think Using Timer inside UpdatePanel to do DataBind() of ListView is not the professional and efficient way to do that? is it ??

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: look into SignalR https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: @dansasu11   ,, I need an example. SignalR is not working for me till now

Comment: @dansasu11  - Each Application is on different Port. for example

Comment: @dansasu11 - http://localhost:8999 for Application

Comment: localhost:8995 for Website

Answer (score 0):

I think The Best way is use SignalR